# Displaying value from one table that doesn't have an id number in another

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've been on this for awhile now with no solutions. I've tried similar codes with similar questions still with no results.

I have 2 tables with an id column that are link to one another. On the second table an id is assign to a product item. 
The id column on the first table doesn't necessary have every id which are associated to the items on the second table.

How do I write a query to display the items that are NOT listed on the first table
I've tried

```
Select items
From product join shop
Where product.productid != shop.productid;
```

Also tried this

```
Select productid from product
Where productid not in (select productid from shop);
```

With no luck, I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution should work . . . unless `shop.productid` takes on a `NULL` value.  Try this:

```
Select productid
from product
Where productid not in (select productid from shop where productid is not null);
```

Comment: Solved Damn........Speechless....... You made it sound so easy Gordon. It's probably an easy question to you but still.... Amazing thank you

Comment: @JosephNguyen . . . This is a common problem with `not in` and why I recommend using `not exists` instead.